# Unable to select text or other content in <input> tag by mouse angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html, input

Created form in angularjs but if I enter value in input text box and try to select it with mouse by click and dragging over the text or content. I'm not able to select any character.

Searched a lot on net but was not able to find any solution.
Following is my form tag code:

```
<form name='addStudent' ng-submit="addStudentSubmit()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <div class="register">
                                <label>Username</label>
                                <input type="text" name="user" autofocus="autofocus" ng-model="newstudent.username" required="true" value="">
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>

                                <label>First Name</label>
                                <input type="text" name="user" ng-model="newstudent.first_name" required="true" value="">                               
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>

                                <label>Last Name</label>
                                <input type="text" name="user" ng-model="newstudent.last_name" required="true" value="">
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>

                                <label>Password</label>
                                <input type="password" name="user" ng-model="newstudent.password" required="true" value="">
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>

                                <label>Grade</label>
                                <select ng-model="newstudent.grade" class='frmsel'>
                                    <option value="00">00</option>
                                    <option value="0">0</option>
                                    <option value="1">1</option>
                                    <option value="2">2</option>
                                    <option value="3">3</option>
                                    <option value="4">4</option>
                                    <option value="5">5</option>
                                    <option value="6">6</option>
                                    <option value="7">7</option>
                                    <option value="8">8</option>
                                    <option value="9">9</option>
                                    <option value="10">10</option>
                                    <option value="11">11</option>
                                    <option value="12">12</option>
                                    <option value="T">T</option>
                                </select>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>

                                <label>Gender</label>
                                <select ng-model="newstudent.gender" class='frmsel'>
                                    <option value="male">Male</option>
                                    <option value="female">Female</option>
                                </select>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>

                                <label>Class</label>
                                <input type="text" name="user" ng-model="newstudent.class" value="">
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>

                                <label>Photo</label>
                                <input name=photo file-input="photoFile" type="file" accept="image/*" />
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>

                                <hr>
                                <label>&nbsp;</label><button class="bluebtn btn regbtn" style="margin-left:-300px" type="submit">Add Student</button>

                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Comment: Please share your controller code as well. Would be better if you could setup a jsfiddle

Comment: I'm able to select the content via mouse http://jsbin.com/luyemo/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: if i paste code in fiddle then i am also able to select text. its weird issue. Dont know the exact reason why its happening.

https://jsfiddle.net/vqj7eoae/   check the link